# Chrome Extension strange behaviour of onMessage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code in my background.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details){
    if(isfileTypeXYZ(details))
    {   
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(details.tabId, {isFileXYZ: true});
        return { //Stop rendering of frame...
        responseHeaders: [{
          name: 'X-Content-Type-Options', 
          value: 'nosniff'
        }, {
          name: 'X-Frame-Options', 
          value: 'deny'
        }]
      };
    }
}, {
   urls: ['*://*/*'],
   types: ['main_frame']
}, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
```

And in my contentscript I have the following code:

```
var toLoadXYZ = 0;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, _, sendMessage){
    if(msg.isFileXYZ)
    {
        toLoadXYZ = 1;
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(toLoadXYZ);
});
```

What I want to do is to detect if a particular file type is being opened and then load an image from a server running on the system itself and display it. I will have to load the image using xhr but I need to get this detection thing working well first. There are two problems that I am facing:

1. The onMessage is not triggered when the url is first loaded - it is after that (refreshing using F5).
2. The value shown in the `alert(toLoadXYZ)` is 0 not 1 even though the debugger shows that the onMessage is triggered (after first load that is - after first load i am refreshing the page using F5).

Here is the manifest file if you want to refer:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "my Extension",
    "version": "1.0",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },

    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "tabs",
        "webNavigation"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["jquery-2.1.4.min","renderXYZ.js"]
    }
  ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [ "http:/*", "https:/*", "ftp:/*", "file:/*", "chrome-extension:/*"]
}
```

What is the cause for this problem? How to fix it? I searched a lot didn't get anything useful please help!!

**UPDATE**

```
function findContentType(responseHeaders)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < responseHeaders.length; i++)
    {
        var header = responseHeaders[i];
        if(header.name.toLowerCase() === "content-type")
            return header.value.toLowerCase();
    }
    return "";
}

function isfileTypeXYZ(details)
{
    var contentType = findContentType(details.responseHeaders);
    if(contentType === "some-mime-type-here")
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you post the isfileTypeXYZ too?

Comment: @CViejo: Yes, edited the question.

Comment: 'onHeadersReceived' happens before the content scripts are loaded, 'chrome.runtime.onMessage' cannot have been triggered on the 'renderXYZ.js' file. How did you check that it was?

Comment: @CViejo: By putting an alert. Also by putting a breakpoint in the debugger

Comment: The alert is called on document ready, not in the onMessage handler, which is the one that sets toLoadXYZ to 1. That one is not being called..

Comment: @CViejo: The alert that I just mentioned is not in the present code that I have posted. You can assume it was in the right place inside onMessage. Plus as I said the debugger goes inside onMessage.

Comment: Yes, I see now what's happening

Answer (score 2):

`chrome.runtime.onMessage` is beeing called, but it's being called on the content script of the previous request. Since you're refreshing the page, `tabId` doesn't change so you send the message to the content script of the previous page, right before the new body gets loaded, that's why you're seeing this behaviour. Maybe clearer like this:

1. First URL call.
2. `onHeadersReceived` gets called
3. You call `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` but it doesn't trigger anything since the content script is not loaded yet.
4. The tab loads the body of the request and the content scripts. Document ready gets called.
5. You refresh the tab. `onHeadersReceived` gets called for this new request but the contents of the tab are STILL the ones of the previous request. This is where you see your alert and why the `toLoadXYZ` is 0.

Comment: Ya got it!! But how do I acheive what I want to do then?

Comment: Hm...do you actually need to do that? I mean, if you want to modify the request, why do you need to communicate with the content script?

Comment: What I want to do is this: If a file of a particular mime type is being loaded, I need to stop chrome's default rendering of it. Then send a request to the server with the file data. The server renders the file and sends me back the data and I need to display it.